# What happens when a previously "FETCHED" url is removed on the web server side and StormCrawler goes to it again?

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

We have lots of sites being updated, added, and deleted. I'm curious as to how Stormcrawler handles a site with a url that has been previously "FETCHED", when the next time SC reaches it it has been removed and either generates a redirect or a 404.  What happens to the content that is from the old version of the page, in the "Index" index?

I know the url in the "Status" index probably changes to "REDIRECTION" or "FETCH ERROR" or something, but what about the content itself? Is it deleted? Is it left?  I am trying to figure out how SC reacts here and if I have to work at cleaning up these orphaned docs in the "Index" index.

I would expect SC to delete the content if it's no longer there, but I thought I would ask to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, a missing URL will get a FETCH_ERROR status, which after being retried a number of times (param *max.fetch.errors* - default 3) will turn into an ERROR status.

The content will be deleted if you connect a DeletionBolt to the status updater, see [example topology](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/ESCrawlTopology.java#L85).